# Convert HTML form declaration to Razor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I convert this line:

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode
    (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])" method="post" id="openid_form">
```

...to Razor, e.g. something looks similar to this:

`(@using(Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using( Html.BeginForm( "Authenticate", "[controller name here]", 
    new { ReturnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] ) }, 
    FormMethod.Post ) ) {

    @* form here *@
}
```

You want to use the `BeginForm()` overload which allows route values to be passed, and a form method to be specified. This overload also requires the name of your controller.

Many helper methods use anonymous types as shorthand for name/value pairs.

For example, `new { ReturnUrl = "foo" }` will be turned into a `RouteValueDictionary` with a single item having "ReturnUrl" as the key, and "foo" as the value. This will then be provided to a matching action method.